# Why doesn't the window resize to the correct height?

Tags: javascript, dom, safari

I want to resize my safari browser window to match the height of a div with id 'po'.
I have the following javascript:

```
    var divHeight = document.getElementById('po').offsetHeight;
    console.log(divHeight);
    divHeight = divHeight + 30;
    var y = parseInt(divHeight,10);
    var w=window.innerWidth;
    window.resizeTo(w,y);
    console.log(divHeight);
```

The output of the console is:

```
83
113
```

But the window gets resized to an actual inner height of only 30!
Why isn't the window resizing correctly? If I measure the div (it contains a table), the height of the div is indeed 83. So why won't the window size match? How to fix it?

Comment: Is it because you are logging `divHeight` after adding 30 to it?  If you are looking for the window height, you might want to use something like: `var windowSize = window.innerHeight;` and log `windowSize`

Comment: I don't understand why logging divHeight should affect window.resizeTo. Can you explain?

Comment: I removed logging, but the window still resizes to the incorrect height. I don't think logging has anything to do with it.

Comment: Sorry, I was just pointing out that you were likely logging the wrong thing if you were looking at it from a troubleshooting standpoint.  Do you have any other supporting code or a Fiddle by chance?

Comment: I don't know what a fiddle is. This is the first time I'm really coding with javascript. I normally code in objective-c. The remaining supporting code is irrelevant. This is the only code that changes the window size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my calculation and misunderstanding how window.resizeTo() works.

The size that window.resizeTo() sizes to includes the chrome(scrollbars, address bar,favourites bar, etc)! Once I added some "padding" to include that, it worked as expected.